# Jquery animate left is not working, what's wrong?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using jQuery's `animate()` and it just doesn't work. I'm trying to get a div to slide off another div that's containing it and has `overflow:hidden`. I've tried every combination of `left` on the animate and nothing. Just to make sure, I also tried changing the width of the div (gallery) and it does change the width, but not the left.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
function an() {

  //$('#gallery').fadeOut();
  //$('#gallery').animate({left:'-=1000'},'slow');
  $('#gallery').animate({
    'left': '+=100px'
  }, 'slow');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" style="position:relative; height:137px; overflow:hidden; width:1000px; border:3px solid #ff0000;">
  <div id="gallery" style="background-color:#033; width:100px; height:137px;"></div>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="an(); return false;">test</a>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLdRW/1/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should give the #gallery div a `position:relative` and then it works fine.

```js
function an() {

  //$('#gallery').fadeOut();
  //$('#gallery').animate({left:'-=1000'},'slow');
  
  $('#gallery').animate({
    'left': '-=700px'
  }, 'slow');

}
```

```css
#gallery {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" style="position:relative; height:137px; overflow:hidden; width:1000px; border:3px solid #ff0000;">
  <div id="gallery" style="background-color:#033; width:100px; height:137px;"></div>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="an(); return false;">test</a>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cLdRW/8/)

By the way, you should avoid inline JavaScript (like onclick) and CSS whenever possible. Also, the `align` attribute was deprecated in HTML 4.01 and eliminated in HTML5.

Comment: The example provided by the submitter had errors outside of the solution.  Do follow the suggestion about the inline scripting.

Comment: wow, that worked... that was killing me. How do you recommend i do the onclick?

Comment: @Damien - Since you have a link but you're really using it like a button, create a button (or perhaps even a span or div) and then target that with jQuery. Ex: `$('button').click(function(){an();});`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cLdRW/23/

Comment: is there an advantage to doing this? Also, what do i use alternatively for align?

Comment: @Damien - `margin:0 auto` on the gallery div should do it and the advantage is separation of the content from the presentation.

Comment: For reference, `left` only applies to positioned elements. See [documentation for `left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `position: relative` to all attributes that are under the main attribute, to activate the `animate()` function.

```
<div style='position:fixed'>
<div style='position:relative'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add:

```
style="position:relative;"
```

to the element that you want to move.

- you don't have to add it to it's container div.
- it will be relative to it's container and will move according to it's position.