# Jquery positioning not working in animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

i'm trying to add animation on page scroll like this

```
$(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function() {
              if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                  $('.bottle').fadeIn().animate({left: '500px', opacity: '0.4'}, "slow");
              }
            });
 });
```

opacity works but left does not work, i tried to do this  one also

```
animate({position:'relative', left: '500px'});
```

if you can help me with it that would be great

Comment: Have you declared any CSS for that element? How is it positioned?

Comment: position is not mentioned  in css

Comment: can you add the HTML and CSS for the `.bottle` element so we can replicate the issue

Comment: `left` only applies to positioned elements. See [left @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left). Here's [an illustration](http://jsfiddle.net/m7otwuee/).

Comment: is not it ok ? animate({position:'relative', left: '500px'});

Comment: yes done , thank you @MDN

Comment: Also, [`position` cannot be animated](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties). But you can set the position via CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery animate left is not working, what's wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522799/jquery-animate-left-is-not-working-whats-wrong)